# After creating a symlink from PlayOnLinux steamapps to Windows steamapps, should games appear as installed in Steam?

Tags: wine, games, symbolic-link, playonlinux, steam

I was able to successfully install Steam via PlayOnLinux. I can launch Steam, browse the store, see my library, etc. After I did that step, I followed these instructions to create a symlink from PlayOnLinux steamapps to Windows steamapps:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Save_space_on_dual-boot_machines

Since those instructions are for Wine, I had to change the command a bit for PlayOnLinux:

```
cd "/home/dave/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam"
mv steamapps steamapps.bak
ln -s "/host/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps" steamapps
```

My question is: now that I've created the symlink, should my games appear as installed in my library on Steam? Because they aren't... I thought the whole point of this step was to make Steam see the games already installed and not ask to download them again.

Answer (score 1):

They should be there. Try deleting everything EXCEPT steam.exe and steamapps and launch Steam.  It should pick them up.
But a warning.  Some games really really hate simlinks.  For example Portal 2 and Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 will not work with simlinks.  I forget exactly why.  There are other games that I haven't mentioned (or run into). So you'll have to watch out for that.
Half-Life
Half-Life 2
both work with simlinked steamapps.  It is really a touch and go.  You have to see what games work and what games don't.